# how to solve HostResourceResolver error in angular?

Tags: angular

*I am learning angular, i was following a course but this error occurred. I am not able to resolve it.*

This is my first time angular

Error

```
**ERROR in HostResourceResolver: could not resolve ./product-list.compoment.html in context of /home/user/angular/Angular-GettingStarted/APM-Start/src/app/products/product-list.component.ts)**
```

**app.component.ts**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
      selector: 'pm-root',
      template: `
        <div><h1> {{ pageTitle }} </h1>
          <pm-products></pm-products>
        </div>
      `
    })

    export class AppComponent{
      pageTitle: string = 'Acme Product Management'
    }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { ProductListComponent } from './products/product-list.component';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ProductListComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

**product-list.component.ts**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
        selector: 'pm-products',
        templateUrl: './product-list.compoment.html'
    })

    export class ProductListComponent{
        pageTitle: string = 'Product List';
    }
```

I tried changing

```
   @Component({
        selector: 'pm-products',
        templateUrl: './product-list.compoment.html' 

      // to

      //    templateUrl: '.products/product-list.compoment.html' to

    })
```

Comment: check your index.js file what is in it?

Comment: There is no `index.js`

Comment: oh i mean index.html file... what is in `index.html` file.

Answer (score 0):

My case below code working properly, it might be help for yours too...

## server.component.ts file

@Component({
      selector:'app-server',
      templateUrl:'server.component.html',
})

## app.component.ts file

import { ServerComponent } from './server/server.component';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
       AppComponent,
       ServerComponent
]
})

I am using angular 10.1.3 version